# Serve sitemap from S3 to react static page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, redirect, amazon-s3

I'm creating my sitemap using Rails and hosting it on `S3`. The front-end of my website is based on `React`. The `content_disposition` of the uploaded file is `attachment` so just going to the URL automatically downloads the file or at least gives the user the option to download it.

Is there a way I can create a React page www.somedomain.com/sitemap.xml.gz going to which would automatically call the attachment from S3 and make it available for download so that search engines can understand it?